# How often are people vaccinated in the unlikely event of biological-germ-warfare (ex: anthrax and ricin)?

Tags: vaccination, infectious-diseases

How often are people vaccinated in the unlikely event of biological-germ-warfare (Example: anthrax and ricin)? A few years ago, a few letters laced with anthrax and ricin were sent via mail to individuals, and the media was all over it because... well... it's quite frightening to know that traces of these bio-agents were extremely potent and fatal.

I know that brucellosis and meliodosis have also been considered as biological weapons in biological warfare.

- Is there a way to be vaccinated from such agents?
- Are people vaccinated based on their risk of exposure (politicians,
  postal workers, soldiers in the military, etc)?
- How often is it done?
- At what point does the CDC or WHO (or whoever decides these things)
  decides it best to vaccinate individuals/populations against a known
  biological weapon?